# Return an anonymous class that adds a field to a named class

Tags: .net, anonymous-class

I have a method that returns a class instance. e.g.

```
public User GetUser(int id) { return new User(); }
```

In most cases this is good enough, but I have one case in which I need another filed added to the `User` object. Without creating a named class that extends this class, how can I do that?

Is it possible with anonymous classes? maybe something like this:

```
public object GetExtendedUser(int id)
{
    return GetUser(id).extendsAnonymous(new {
         avatar: "~/avatar/bird.png"   
        });
}
```

From what I've seen up to now it's not possible. Id have to either declare a named class or explicitly declare the original fields in an anonymous class:

```
public object GetExtendedUser(int id)
{
    User user = GetUser(id);
    return new {
         username: user.username,
         role = user.role,
         ...
         avatar: "~/avatar/bird.png"   
        };
}
```

But that's ugly.

Is there any nice solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DynamicObject`.  If you change your User object to inherit from DynamicObject and implement a couple of simple overrides you'll be able to add properties to the object.

```
class User : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = properties[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Invalid Property!";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        properties[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}

public dynamic GetExtendedUser(int id)
{
    dynamic user = new User();
    user.ExtraProperty = "TADA!";
    return user;
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    dynamic user = GetExtendedUser(123);

    Console.WriteLine(user.ExtraProperty);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: That looks like it could work, but it's a bit of an overkill for my situation

Comment: Also, I don't want to change `User`

Comment: If you don't want to change User you could use an ExpandoObject and use reflection to iterate over the properties on the User object and add them to the ExpandoObject but that's probably even more like overkill! :)